# Django Role based permissions varies on different project

Tags: django, django-models

Hi i am working on Django to build project management app, in that i have 100s of users & 50 plus projects.
where single user are involved in multiple projects with different role. now how to give project-role based permission ??

For example.
Let say user "Arnold" is working on "[project-A as Manager, project-B as Vendor , project-C as Artist]",
*As a manager arnold will get all permissions in project-A,
*As a vendor arnold will get read-only permissions in project-B,
*As a Artist arnold will get read,write and update permissions in project-C,

So now tell me how can i design model relation as mentioned above ?

Comment: What about using django guardian and groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it.

Start with standard User object from django (I always use that for my User and then abstract out from there).

I'd then create a Roles object.  Role has a name like Vendor, Owner, Artist, etc.

Then I'd create a junction object between User, Role, and Project.

```
class Role(...):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Project(...):
     ...

class ProjectParticipant(...):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Then I could create a custom @user_passes_test permission rule in the views that checks to make sure that the user has appropriate relationship to the project.  I am assuming that you'll have a view which exposes the project and then within that expose different actions by role on ProjectParticipant.

Comment: Thank you for reply. one more question, in above solution how to avoid same user in same project can have multiple role ?

Comment: I wasn't sure that you'd want to preclude that.  You probably want some sort of function that "Provisions Project Access".  I say that because you may want to handle promotions like used to have limited access but now has full access.  Or possibly demotions "used to have full access and now has less".  In other words, right or wrong, I'd enforce this in code vice in the data model because eventually you'll want to apply your logic to the process of creating, updating, or deleting the participation association.

Comment: got it.. Thnx much